# Contesting a wrongfully rejected edit

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

Yesterday, I made a reasonable [edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22549975) to improve an answer I had personally benefited from, in the hope that others would find it easier to understand should they face the same issue. To my surprise, my edit was rejected for both of the following reasons:

> This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.

And:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Neither of which, in my opinion, applies to my suggested edit. What do you think of this? I'm now hesitant to resubmit it again and, to be honest, even submit further edit suggestions because I'm now rendered unsure of what an edit suggestion should actually be in order to be accepted.

Comment: The edit looks reasonable, maybe the comment *improved answer expression* can be a bit (A LOT!) more extensive on what you changed and it looks like you've invented text about the `set`  method that wasn't in the post. Reviewers might go *huh?* on that if it appears out of nowhere.

Comment: @rene I avoid too much detail in the comment as to not confuse the reviewer, regarding the `set` method text I added, it was to further help future readers in understanding how to fix the issue, which is the main goal of an answer.

Comment: That edit was fine and really should  have been approved. I did so now.

Comment: @AchrafAlmouloudi in that case you risk your suggested edits will get rejected, also in the future.

Comment: Just be aware, the "spam or vandalism" rejection reason (the first one) is shown directly above "no improvement whatsoever" (the second one). It's likely that the first reviewer misclicked and meant to click "no improvement whatsoever", as your edit clearly did not have the intention of harm. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh2B2.png).

Comment: Just for the records: 2 should always be written as two. And the code formatting could have been improved. But other than that I see no reason to reject.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for the approval, I really got confused about it.

Comment: @rene I understand that and will try to do as you advised in my future edit suggestions.

Comment: @BDL I totally agree, I was more focused on fixing the text (it was bad) and so totally missed noticing that code formatting was equally a bad.

Comment: @AchrafAlmouloudi: I also think your edit should have been approved, however, you should also have removed the closing: "Hope this helps someone else out there." This is just noise.

Comment: @honk I wasn't aware that's considered noise, I'll make sure to remove similar stuff in my future edits and not do it myself, thank you.

Comment: @AchrafAlmouloudi: You are welcome! Thank you for listening to the Meta crowd ;) Regaring the "noise" topic, [this Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/2675154) is quite interesting.

Comment: I personally dislike it when edits are rejected with the "superfluous" reason. To be clear there *is* a time and place for it, e.g., if it changes few words from American English to British English spelling (or vice versa) and that's it. But I've also seen it applied where it seems to be used as "the edit didn't change the answer enough to make it different" whereas improving grammar and re-writing a sentence here and there should be fine it it makes the answer even slightly easier to read. That's the point of an edit, after all - improving it. And this edit was a clear improvement.

Comment: Also, a personal anecdote - there was an edit on my own post from some user and it was rejected by reviewers. The edit was to fix my grammar usage. Both reviewers said it was "superfluous" when what I had written was *factually* wrong, not just an alternative way of writing it. Since it was a minor edit (a couple of words), apparently they thought it's not enough of a change and hit it with "superfluous". Being the owner of the post, I was at least able to override their decision.

Comment: I've seen more cases of this, where perfectly good edits get rejected. IMO, the problem is that the audits for this type of review are all negative -- if you reject all edits you will never be wrong in the audits. We should include some audits that need to be accepted to weed out this type of reviewer.

Comment: How about this one: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22527542 ? And yes, I did view the revision history to see what should have been changed... but I was disappointed.

Comment: @VLAZ I also skip editing on similar occasions where I skip editing something because there's a good chance they'll be rejected as "superfluous" just because the "change quantity" was small, while I truly believe the edits could've made the post a bit easier to digest should I've made them. For example, is changing capitalization or fixing indentation enough of an edit to be accepted? That kinda thing.

Comment: @סטנליגרונן This edit suggestion should have definitely been accepted, just adding the commands in a proper code block. Weirdly, the reviewer has chosen to "Reject and Edit" while "Accept and Edit" seems like a more appropriate option if they were so keen to remove the capitalization on "pro" that you added.

Comment: @AchrafAlmouloudi changing capitalisation is most likely OK. If people just never used capital letters or missed them at the start of each sentence or just missed them in a couple of places, I'd say that's good. it's an improvement of the post, after all. I know some reviewers disagree - I've seen rejections because an edit "only" changed stuff like using capital letters *where they should be used*. To me that's an improvement. I don't think there is any *improvement* small enough to not approve. An edit *might* be superfluous if it doesn't offer an improvement.

Comment: *"This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability."* - I've received this exact response from someone else... Is this getting sent around and copy/pasted onto reviews? That's hardly good for giving enough feedback imo.

Comment: @HowardP The vast majority of rejections use stock reasons. You can see what the selection of reject reasons looks like in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh2B2.png) provided by Pikachu the Purple Wizard in their comment above. It's possible to use a type up a custom reason, but it's far easier for a reviewer to click on one of the stock reasons.

Comment: @סטנליגרונן I'm fairly sure the reviewer chose _Reject and Edit_ because of the improper code markup for "mysql2-0.3.21". However, your edit suggestion was overall good, so _Improve Edit_ would have been the proper choice. There are a lot of suggestions which sprinkle in incorrect code markup, so I'm guessing the reviewer was annoyed by it and rejected your edit.

Comment: @Makyen I would much prefer if the reviewer actually typed a custom reason instead of using one of those stock reasons, which almost never explain why the edit suggestion was rejected and doesn't help the editor improve in the future.

Comment: Sure, we'd all like to see custom reasons, but they take a lot more time to type out, and when you're dealing with a site the size of Stack Overflow, that is a bit too much to expect. [Related reading](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381129/why-are-canned-responses-a-thing).

Comment: The only thing I see that I would consider wrong is that there are wording changes that appear to be made purely for style reasons. "Note" means "to notice" the way the OP used it so changing it to "Notice" wasn't really an improvement. Edits for clarity are good but you don't have to change something just because it isn't the way you would have said it. (That said, I would not have rejected this edit.)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Your edit was useful, provided a substantial improvement to the post, and therefore should have been approved. The reviewers' rejection reasons were wrong, and suggest that they were not paying close enough attention.

It has since been retroactively [approved by another moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381738/contesting-a-wrongfully-rejected-edit#comment681047_381738), and both of the reviewers have been temporarily banned from reviewing with a link to this Meta post to show them why.

For your future reference, there are two things you should do to further refine how you suggest edits:

1. [Remove all additional "fluff" in posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/2675154) when you are editing them, like the trailing *"Hope this helps someone else out there."* in this case.
2. Write better edit summaries that explain the purpose of your edit. Your summary for this edit was *"Improved answer expression."*, which really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Fair enough. I think reviewers should put more thought into their actions before making unreasonable edit rejections. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @AchrafAlmouloudi that's the point of the review bans. It should get their attention and hopefully they will learn from it.

Comment: "Remove all additional fluff"  (+1)

Comment: 3. Take care when inserting text like the text about `set`. If it is necessary, follow (2)

Comment: This is one example of suggested edit reviews slowly turning lower quality over time. The review queue system breaks when the queue is never empty and this happened in the past. So someone lowered the review bar from 3 out of 5 to 2 out of 3. In this case the OP had the bad luck of getting hit by 2 rookie reviewers (one got it right) and 1 experienced reviewer not paying attention, at once. Not much is needed to for an incorrect review. And since reviewing is dreadfully boring work, I don't blame experienced reviewers from occasionally falling asleep. Review ban seems a bit harsh.

Comment: Somewhat ironically, the edit to this original answer was a substantial change to the original answer, and probably should have just been a separate answer.

Comment: @CodyPiersall meh, I was ok with Cody Gray making the edit. The mods talk and work as a team, so consider it from the both of us ;)

Comment: Excellent response from Martijn and Yvette here!

Comment: @YvetteColomb I was under the impression "no improvement" actually meant "insufficient improvement", at least from previous meta posts. I certainly would have approved this, but I'm not sure a ban is justified in this case (NB: I'm not one of the reviewers). It's also certainly necessary to take into account whether the post should be bumped; in this case it's not terribly old, but I've seen minimal edits on seven-year-old posts that I've outright rejected.

Comment: @jhpratt "no improvement" means "no improvement". That 'post before edit' = 'post after the edit'. There was a bunch of discussion back in the day but this one is used for the specific case that Robert points out in the third paragraph https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239106/213575 Shog said that any improvement, no matter how small, should be either approved or improved upon.

Comment: @CodyPiersall My edit was a substantial change, but it was in keeping with the author's intent. That's [the expectation for edits](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). Now, granted, I cheated a bit, because I know Yvette pretty well, so I know what her intentions are. Still, major edits can be defensible as long as you are keeping within the original spirit and intent of an answer.

Comment: @jhpratt The "too minor" rejection reason was removed a long time back. "No improvement whatsoever" means what it says. It doesn't mean "insufficient improvement". It means that the edit is completely pointless. An example would be fixing the grammar on spam. Another example would be formatting *half* of the code, but leaving the other half untouched. A third example would be a trivial edit that did not improve either the comprehensibility or locatability of a post. You would be within your rights to reject fixing a minor typo in a years-old post on this basis (although others may disagree).

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray. I'll certainly change how I review; I've likely been rejecting far too much.

Comment: Don't forget the "Improve" button, @jhpratt. Braiam has already called this out in an answer below. You have the power to make a partial edit into a complete edit. Say, they went through the drudgery of formatting the code, but forgot to remove "Thanks in advanced". I use "Improve Edit" a lot under those circumstances.

Comment: @jhpratt review bans are stock standard responses to these types of complaints. It gets the attention of the reviewers.

Comment: @Cody _"Now, granted, I cheated a bit, because I know Yvette pretty well, so I know what her intentions are."_ Tangential-but-related observation for no particular reason: for what it's worth, _sometimes_ we can do that "in the wild" too when we know a fellow contributor's contributory style well enough. Although I suppose that's hard to judge! If I'm unsure I'll usually be especially ambivalent in the edit summary or at least leave a comment inviting a quick, undramatic rollback in the event of disagreement. I imagine this being rare in the case of the review queue though!

Comment: For what it's worth, a partial dissent: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382031/1709587

Answer (score 7):

This is an excellent case for peddling the use of "Improve edit". If you believe that the editor missed something, you can improve the edit. It would waste everyone's time rejecting the edit and waiting for an edit that ticks all the boxes, where you could instead do it yourself.

Comment: Also worth noting that it should be acceptable to approve an edit even if it doesn't address 100% of the things in the post. There is a big community here, so one person can, say, format the code and paragraphs, another can fix the grammar and spelling of the same post. For me, I can't tolerate messy formatting, so I go and edit code, usually and fix capital letters in sentences and stuff. However, sometimes a section of text just doesn't flow right and has to be rewritten but I rarely know the best way. Some others seem to be very proficient, so I'm fine leaving it to them.

Comment: @VLAZ heck, sometimes I edit a post several times in quick succession.

Comment: @VLAZ That's great... for you, since you have > 2k. For people like the OP whose edits have to go through review, it's a waste of reviewer's time if the edit is not complete.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I strongly disagree. If the edit is incomplete, the reviewer(s) are still brought to a post that needs improvement, and still get the chance to Improve/Reject and Edit. That's a pretty valid use of reviewer's time.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I fully support partial improvements of posts when I review. If somebody fixed *horrible* formatting of code but doesn't fix a couple of spelling mistakes in the text is fine. I will approve it and can even fix the mistakes myself, if needed. The description of "Appvove" from the review is "edits that clearly improve the post" which is a *different* thing than "Edits that leave no room for other improvements". Increasing a post's quality from (some imagined scale here) 25% to 75% is a "clear improvement". Which fits the approve button. Are there guidelines to say otherwise?

Comment: @HereticMonkey also, if we're talking about "wasting reviewer's time" (like, really? Isn't the point that you have to spend the time ANYWAY?) then rejecting an edit that makes *some* improvements but not *all of the possible* improvements literally takes more time than approving it. Thus we can conclude that a reviewer who rejects *any* improvements is wasting their own time, in addition to possibly the time of others.

Comment: I still think that things would be _much, much better_ if reviewers got pinged/notified when their edit was rejected/improved. How else should they learn unless they habitually review the results of their previous contributions? (Which seems unlikely sadly). Obvs the ban approach is great for particularly egregious cases though IME it takes a while for a "bad" reviewer to garner enough attention for that, and by then a lot of damage can have been done.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit wait? If it's improved upon, what damage was done?

Answer (score 3):

This post is a bit old now, but let me register a minor dissent. The edit contained a mixture of several good, neutral, and bad changes. Given that, I'd argue that rejecting it was *defensible* (even if, on balance, I think it should've been approved), and that the reviewer who rejected the edit with the "superfluous or actively harm readability" reason didn't deserve to be review-banned.

Good changes:

- Capitalising the two uncapitalised sentences
- Converting constructs specific to Indian English (specifically the use of "code"/"codes" as a countable noun rather than a mass noun) to the form that is correct in British/American English, which is more widely recognised
- Converting some full stops at the end of paragraphs before code blocks to colons to make the connection clearer
- Fixing the grammar in the first sentence of the final paragraph
- Fleshing out the instruction in the final sentence
- Pluralising "prefix" to "prefixes" in a context where two prefixes are being talked about

Neutral changes that do neither harm nor good:

- Converting "Note" to "Notice"
- Rearranging word order in the first sentence
- Changing "I noted that" to "However"

Bad changes:

- Changing *"you ll get the same JShint error"* to *"it will throw the same JShint error"* (since the code itself doesn't throw the error)
- Changing "two" to "2". (Most English style guides recommend writing the numbers 0-9 as words in English prose, and only using numerals for negative or multi-digit numbers.)
- Turning the entire final paragraph into a grammatically incorrect *run-on sentence*.

I'd personally say that the good solidly outweighs the bad and would choose to "Improve Edit" if I saw this in review, but I think a reasonable, conscientious reviewer who had carefully read the edit could disagree and take the view that none of the good changes improve the post sufficiently to justify approving an edit that introduces new errors into the answerer's writing. Rounding that perspective off to *"Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability."* seems reasonable to me.

The reviewer who chose *"This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive."* as their rejection reason, on the other hand, doesn't have a leg to stand on and deserves their review ban.

Comment: I would agree that changing "you ll get the same JShint error" to "it will throw the same JShint error" was incorrect on my part (I temporarily missed distinguishing between a JShint error and a JavaScript engine error) and regarding me changing "two" to "2" it was because I genuinely was thinking that was the correct (better?) way, though I would rather classify it as a "neutral" change as it doesn't really harm readability or meaning.

Comment: However, I strongly disagree that the (temporary) ban isn't well deserved, if a reviewer can't be bothered to "Improve Edit" then it would have been wiser from them to skip reviewing this edit and let someone else (like yourself?) do it instead. Rejecting in this case actively harms Stack Overflow's collaborative community spirit, which is more important than anything else. Banning them (again, temporarily) is the correct way to stop them from doing further harm and giving them some time and tips to improve their edit review habits.